# How to loop through a list of values and add it in the designated areas of the code?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have a list of string values

```
c("String1","String2","String3")
```

How do I create a loop or using lapply that would add the list values into areas of the code I want them to be added to?

```
DataFrame_String1<- DataFrame %>%
    filter(.,ID=="String1")

DataFrame_String2<- DataFrame %>%
    filter(.,ID=="String2")

DataFrame_String3<- DataFrame %>%
    filter(.,ID=="String3")
```

Note that the values in the list are added in the title of the dataframe and in the ID section.

Comment: There are syntax errors, i.e. `=` should be `==`.  Instead you can use `%in%` i.e. `filter(ID %in% c("String1", "String2", "String3"))`

Comment: what about for the data frame name as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a loop, then loop over the vector with `lapply` or `purrr::map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
lst1 <- map(c("String1", "String2", "String3"), ~ DataFrame %>%
           filter(ID == .x))
names(lst1) <- str_c("DataFrame_", c("String1", "String2", "String3"))
```

It may be better to keep it in a `list`.  But, we can create objects with `list2env` from a named `list`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```