# How to loop through a list of values and add it in the designated areas of the code within spatial parameters using sf?

Tags: r, loops, lapply, r-sf

This question builds off of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72016411/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-values-and-add-it-in-the-designated-areas-of-the-c) that serves on its own.

I have a list `c("String1","String2","String3")`

Without the loop the code looks like this

```r
Data_String1<- DF2 %>%
mutate(`New String`= if_else(lengths(st_intersects(DF2, DataFrame_String1, join = st_within))>0,DataFrame_String1$ID,"N"))%>%
filter(.,`New String`!="N")

Data_String2<- DF2 %>%
mutate(`New String`= if_else(lengths(st_intersects(DF2, DataFrame_String2, join = st_within))>0,DataFrame_String2$ID,"N"))%>%
filter(.,`New String`!="N")

Data_String3<- DF2 %>%
mutate(`New String`= if_else(lengths(st_intersects(DF2, DataFrame_String3, join = st_within))>0,DataFrame_String3$ID,"N"))%>%
filter(.,`New String`!="N")
```

Using the principles of the solution shown in the previous code I tried to implement here:

```r
lst1 <- map(c("String1", "String2", "String3") ~DF2 %>%
    mutate(`New String`= if_else(lengths(st_intersects(DF2, c("String1","String2","String3"), join = st_within)) > 0, .x, "N")) %>%
    filter(.,`New String`!="N")
```

However I receive an error message like this

> x no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "character"` which makes me wonder if the dataframe loses being an spatial entity.

Comment: Where do *DataFrame_String1-3* derive? From using `list2env` in prior accepted answer?

Comment: Yes they were derived from the previous answer. These exist. already, but they are based off the same list file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extend from previous solution:

```r
df_lst <- map(c("String1", "String2", "String3"), ~ DataFrame %>% 
    filter(ID == .x)
)

DF2_subs <- map(df_lst, ~ DF2 %>% 
    mutate(`New String`= if_else(
        lengths(st_intersects(DF2, .x, join = st_within)) > 0,
        .x$ID,
        "N")) %>%
    filter(`New String`!="N")
)
```

Otherwise pass in actual data frames and not vector of strings

```r
DF2_subs <- map(list(Data_String1, Data_String2, Data_String3), ~ DF2 %>% 
    mutate(`New String`= if_else(
        lengths(st_intersects(DF2, .x, join = st_within)) > 0,
        .x$ID,
        "N")) %>%
    filter(`New String`!="N")
)
```